# python remove hex first two characters from string.

Tags: python, hex

I have read a line from a file and I have this:
'Caf\xc3\xa9'

I want to remove all the '\' and 'x' chars in the string. However, these are not indicidul chars and they are hex values. How do I do this?

Output:
Cafc3a9

Comment: Do you want `Caf` which are ascii to remain the same?

Comment: Do you realized that this string is actually only five characters long? The last two characters are shown in hex as `'\xc3\xa9'`. It's difficult to understand why you would effectively want to convert their values to regular hex digits and place them in the string with the normal values...

Comment: What you're asking for is a bad idea. What you *really* want is to do 'Caf\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf-8'), which will produce the Unicode string u'Café'. Read the Python [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 has the various string operations built-in. Try using the replace() method.

Its documentation is found here on the official page:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html

```
sample = r'Caf\xc3\xa9'
output = sample.replace(r'\x', '')
print(output)
```

Note: The 'r' just means that python should treat the contents inside of the parenthesis as a raw string and therefore not use the backslash to do any character escapes.

Answer (score -1):

If a string appears as `'\xab\xcd'` the \ and x are *not* actually part of the string - and neither are the abcd. Instead, there are only two characters, one with value 0xab and one with value 0xcd.

You can write

```
'\xab\xcd'.encode('hex')
```

to get 'abcd'